# How do I pin a Flatpak application to a specific version to prevent it from being updated?

Tags: software-updates, flatpak

I have issues with a newer version of a Flatpak for reasons unrelated to this question, and I would therefore like to "pin" the Flatpak to an older version so that I don't manually need to roll it back whenever I update my Flatpaks. I found [this issue](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/3078), but it doesn't explain how to actually do it. How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `flatpak-mask` for this: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flatpak-mask.1.html

For example, if you want to prevent updates to Signal desktop for whatever reason:

```
$ flatpak mask org.signal.Signal
```

This will make Flatpak ignore Signal when updating.

If you later want to remove this, you can do this:

```
$ flatpak mask --remove org.signal.Signal
```

And if you want to list all currently masked patterns:

```
$ flatpak mask
```

Comment: Personally I needed to use `sudo` for these commands (except last), even though I normally don't need sudo for flatpak. It's the same with `flatpak update`.

Comment: **Warning** This will avoid also security updates.  
In the case of Signal should be particularly avoided.